# Conditionally pass optional parameter to widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a custom widget which can optionally be passed a `size` property. If present, this value should be passed to the `size` property of an `Icon()` widget within my own widget.

Is there a way to only pass this value if it's present?

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double size;
  MyWidget({this.size});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Icon(
      iconData: IconData(),
      size: // Don't pass size here if not present
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There currently is no way to do this.  You either would need to conditionally invoke the constructor `return size == null ? Icon(iconData: IconData()) : Icon(iconData: iconData(), size: size)` or you would need to explicitly pass the default value for `Icon`'s `size` parameter.

Comment: Here is one proposal: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/219.  I'm pretty sure there are others.

Comment: Good to see there is discussion around this. I'm happy to accept this as an answer so future visitors can confidently know there's no way to do it in Dart at the moment.

Comment: I bumped into the same problem. Man. They should change this.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar problem where I have to optionally display an icon in a button.

With null safety, what you're trying to do can be achieved this way

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? size;
  MyWidget ({this.size});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Icon(
      iconData:IconData(),
      size: size, // Don't pass size here if not present
    );
  }
}
```

And used like this

```
 StackIcon()
```

or like this

```
 StackIcon(size: 100.0)

If you supply the size parameter the icon will make use of it, otherwise it uses the default size of the icon.
```